# Load Testing Drupal by JMeter

Tags: drupal-7, jmeter, load-testing

I want to load test DRUPAL by JMeter, but when I run my test plan (it is about updating cart in drupal commerce) it gives me this error:"The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page."
I think the value of form-token is invalid. I use regular expressin for form-token with this regular expression: name="form_token" value="(.+?)".it still does not update cart

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you verify "form_token" value in request, by adding "Debug sampler". I am think that "form_token" is not extracted.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of different reasons for this, most probably:

1. Missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
2. Missing or improperly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)

The solution is comparing the request, which is being generated by JMeter with the request, coming from the real browser - they need to be identical (apart from dynamic bits like cookies or this `form_param`).

- In JMeter you can use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to check request and response details, variables and cookie values, etc.
- In browser you should have [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) option which allows inspecting the same